# How to Remove All markers from googlemap not mapview.clear (ios objective-c)

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to remove existing all markers from google maps, we can do by `map.clear` but I don't want to remove everything(Polyline, polygons) on map, I just want to remove only markers

I am creating markers based on array count

```
-(void)annotationCreationForCoordinatesOfArray:(NSMutableArray *)array
{
     for (int i=0; i<array.count; i++)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue], [[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]);

        mark = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];

        NSString *annoNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i];
        mark.title = annoNumber;
        mark.map = _mapView;
        mark.tracksViewChanges = YES;
        mark.draggable = YES;
        mark.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Mappin.png"];

    }
}
```

Comment: make your specific marker `nil`.

Comment: If I set marker=nil, or marker.map=nil the only last marker is removed

Comment: No, for this you have to set ID for each marker and then fetch that particular marker and then nil it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code its work for me.

Create global array

```
NSMutableArray *removalMarkerArray;
```

Now add all marker in global array

```
   removalMarkerArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 -(void)annotationCreationForCoordinatesOfArray:(NSMutableArray *)array{

    for (int i=0; i<array.count; i++){

    CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue], [[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]);

    mark = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];

    NSString *annoNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i];
    mark.title = annoNumber;
    mark.map = _mapView;
    mark.tracksViewChanges = YES;
    mark.draggable = YES;
    mark.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Mappin.png"];

    [removalMarkerArray addObject:mark];

     }
  }
```

Then where you want to clear all marker

```
  for (GMSMarker *marker in removalMarkerArray ){
        marker.map = nil;
   }
```